# Concrete math generalized josephus recursion understanding 1.15

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, binary

I am studying through the josephus problem in concrete math , Here is the equation of binary form 
$$f(1) = α ;$$
$$f(2n + j) = 2f(n) + β_j ,$$
$$\text{ for } j = 0, 1 \text{ and } n \geq 1$$
this part I understand , now the unfolding of the recurrence

\begin{align*}f(b_m b_{m−1}...b_1 b_0)_2 &= 2f(b_m b_{m−1} . . . b_1)_2+ β_{b_0}\\&=4f(b_mb_{m−1}...b_2)_2 + 2β_{b_1} + β_{b_0}\\&=
2^mf((b_m)_2) +2^{m−1}β_{b_{m−1}} + · · · +2β_{b_1}+β_{b_0}
\\&=2^mα + 2^{m−1}β_{b_{m−1}} + · · · + 2β_{b_1} + β_{b_0}\end{align*}

I mean what just happened here ?where did this $β_{b_0}$ came from ?There was just two constants $α$ , $β$ and now there are many. Can someone explain pease?

Comment: Sorry if I don't read all the detail, but you said you understood the part with $\beta_j$, which are $\beta_{something}$...

Comment: Yes $β_i$ , can only have two values , in the book it was α and β. I just don't understand how unfolding happened here?

Comment: There are three constants: $\alpha$, $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$. Each $b_i$ is either $0$ or $1$, so $\beta_{b_i}$ becomes either $\beta_0$ or $\beta_1$ depending on the value of $b_i$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $j \in \{0, 1\},$ so you have $\beta_0, \beta_1.$ From the fact that $b_m b_{m−1}\dots b_1 b_0$ is a binary representation of $2n + j$ we have that to get $n$ from $2n + j$ we need to shift bits right and LSB (least significant bit) goes to subscript of $\beta.$ E.g.

$$f(101) = 2f(10) + \beta_1.$$